# Android Linkify text in dialog

Tags: java, android, email, url, linkify

Hi I've gone through all of the different linkify tutorials I could find but none of them work here is my current code:

```
final SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Please send any questions to email@fake.com");
            Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Warning!")
                   .setMessage(s)
                   .setCancelable(false)
                   .setPositiveButton("Accept", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                       }
                   })
                   .setNegativeButton("Decline", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            Activity.this.finish();
                       }
                   }).show();
```

However when I actually run the app it shows the text like blue and underlined as if it were linked but selecting the text doesn't prompt to open the email app. I've also tried with urls and the browser doesn't work is there something that's missing?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In order to have a `clickable` area on dialog you need to use `TextView` (View) and set `autoLink=all` in layout file or invoke `setAutoLinkMask()` method from within the code.

```
final SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Please send any questions to email@fake.com");

//added a TextView       
final TextView tx1=new TextView(this);
tx1.setText(s);
tx1.setAutoLinkMask(RESULT_OK);
tx1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Warning!")
  .setCancelable(false)
  .setPositiveButton("Accept", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
       }
      })
  .setNegativeButton("Decline", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               finish();
      }
     })
  .setView(tx1)
  .show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's Kotlin in case it's helpful:

```
val s = SpannableString(getString(R.string.actions_list_info_button_body))
val tx1 = TextView(context!!)
tx1.text = s
tx1.autoLinkMask = RESULT_OK
tx1.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
```

The rest is the same.

The result likely will not look great so you probably will want to add some padding as well:

```
// Adjust Padding to dp
val scale: Float = resources.displayMetrics.density
val dpAsPixels: Int = (25 * scale + 0.5f).toInt()
text.setPadding(dpAsPixels,20,dpAsPixels,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can reuse the `TextView` created.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;

builder.setMessage(R.string.yourMessage);

Dialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.setOnShowListener(d -> {
    TextView text = dialog.getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
    text.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL);
    text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
});
```